# How to get original error thrown by another API?

Tags: java, spring, rest, error-handling, jhipster

Forgive me, if something I say is not totally correct, I am learning.

I have a web application **A** generated with JHipster. It is the main one that the end users will use. I have a second web application **B** that has a its own database, and frontend with what you can manipulate the data in the database. Application **A** can request data from **B** through a gateway, which then requests data from **B** and maybe some others, formats the data and sends it back to **A**.

If I were to raise a `BadRequestAlertException` in **A** backend, the ExceptionTranslator that JHipster created will catch it and use the errorKey parameter to translate it. But if **A** requests data from **B** and **B** raises a `BadRequestAlertException`, the ExceptionTranslator in **B** catches the error, but in **A** I get a `HttpClientErrorException`. I would like to get the original error that was thrown, so that ExceptionTranslator of **A** could catch it and translate the error as I want to show an error message to the user. I could read the errorKey from the response body of HttpClientErrorException using `getResponseBodyAsString()` and throw `BadRequestAlertException` again, but all this doesn't seem right, because I have to start parsing the error string. How can get the original error or is there a better way to do this kind of thing?

Comment: You would need to modify **B** so that it returns an error response which **A** can interpret more accurately, such as by subclassing `BadRequestAlertException` with a more specific message. If B is not publicly accessible but serves as a backend to A, you could make it return the exact error that you would like A to display, and show it to the user unchanged. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking is not possible.
Service A and B are two different services, so you can't get the actual exception from B inside A - all you can is get the HTTP response B returns (A translates it to `HttpClientErrorException` but this exception is generated inside A, not B).

You don't have to generate an exception out of it, you can simply take the body and status you got from B and return it